# Installation problem with .deb file

Tags: files, deb

How to install a software in Ubuntu with a .deb file?

```
administrator@administrator-VirtualBox:/tmp$ sudo apt-get -i SmartclassCTS.deb
[sudo] password for administrator: 
E: Command line option 'i' [from -i] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

Answer (score 4):

You either can install it via `dpkg` which really has the option `-i` for installing like so:

```
sudo dpkg -i SmartclassCTS.deb
```

Or you can use apt for that with the `install` option:

```
sudo apt install ./SmartclassCTS.deb
```

Or as an alternative to dpkg which not resolves dependencies you can use `gdebi` which is not installed by default but you can find it in the universe repositories:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gdebi
sudo gdebi SmartclassCTS.deb
```